# Is the set of non-degenerate symmetric matrices with signature (p,q) simply connected?

Tags: general-topology

Let $M=\big\{A\in\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})|\;A^T=A\;,\; A \text{ has signature  }(p,q)\big\}\;$ denote the set of real non-degenerate symmetric matrices with signature $(p,q)$, where $p$ is the number of positive eigenvalues and $q$ the number of negative ones. Then $M$ is a non-compact manifold, and one can show that it is path-connected.

Now I would like to know (and prove) for which values of $p$ and $q$  the space $M$ is simply connected.

My intuition tells me that $M$ is simply connected for $p=n$, $q=0\;$ (i.e. positive definite matrices) and for $p=0$, $q=n$, while all other values lead to non-simply connected $M$. But how could this be proven?

(Maybe I should mention that the path-connectedness can be shown by considering $M$ a homogeneous space, $M=\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})/\text{O}(p,q)$, where $\text{O}(p,q)\,$ is the semi-orthogonal group.)

Thanks for any help!